# Improper Privilege Management in shelljs - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4rq4-32rv-6wp6

Tags: npm, shelljs

It seems I can stuck in an npm loop.

When I run `npm install` or `npm update` I am told that I have "2 high severity vulnerabilities" and when I run an `npm audit` I am told that "Improper Privilege Management in shelljs - [https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4rq4-32rv-6wp6"](https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-4rq4-32rv-6wp6%22)

I have tried everything I can think of to solve this and have been to every google link. It just seems stuck. Help!

I've tried to update shelljs/resolve this issue in many different ways

- `npm install [-g] shelljs`
- manually by downloading the updated file and replacing the code in the files on my system
- navigating to the path `project\platforms\ios\cordova` and running `npm install shelljs`
- resetting the node path first `export NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g)`
- resetting the temp cache `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cachnpm audit`
- removing the node modules and then reinstalling npm
- resetting node module permissions
- Uninstall shelljs `npm uninstall shelljs` so it could be reinstalled

I'm running out of ideas and google links. I cannot install new plugins, run my project or do ANYTHING without fixing this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with Ionic 6, after upgrading from Ionic 5.

The way I solved it

1. Removed npm packages that depends on shelljs
2. Uninstall shelljs
3. Install shelljs latest version. (npm i --save-dev shelljs@0.8.5)
4. Add back removed packages
5. npm install

And the issues were resolved.